# no error but length of dataframe doesn't match real length can't understand why

Tags: python, pandas

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 19398698 entries, 0 to 429364
Data columns (total 5 columns):
0       object
1       float64
2       object
date    object
name    object
dtypes: float64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 888.0+ MB
```

len(df) = 19398698

but real length its actually 429364, I don't know where this length of 19398698 comes from, why was it produced, or how to fix it (in case that produces future problems)

edit: data was created through for loops and concat.

```
for folder in os.listdir(folder_path):
  for file in os.listdir(f'{folder_path}/{folder}'):
    os.chdir(f"{folder_path}/{folder}')
    if file == 'AMAT.txt':
      df = pd.read_csv(f'{file}', header=None, sep='  ')
      df['date'] = os.getcwd().split('/')[5]
      df['name'] = f'{file}'
      all_files = pd.concat([all_files, df])
    print(f'{folder}_{file}')
    os.chdir("/content")
```

Comment: Do you have duplicated index values?

Comment: You're asking us to play 20 questions with you... "where is your data"... "what does it look like"... "how was it created"... etc etc. Can you please provide a little detail that makes it easier to understand the context here?

Comment: Stef answer is correct but we will need to see how you built this dataframe. I am guessing that you did some sort of join with multiple dataframes that caused duplication if you are seeing your dataframe increase 5x that expected amount.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I edited to show how I created. Yes this has to be duplication I suppose.

Comment: @G.Anderson yes sir. I'm in the process of figuring out how to remove this issue. or if you could enlighten me how to avoid it to begin with

Comment: @cs95 You are right, I edited my question to show how I created the dataframe.

Comment: One place to check would be to print the `shape` of `all_files` after each `concat` to watch which files are adding the most to the length, and also check your output from `print(f'{folder}_{file}')` to make sure you're not hiting the same files twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously have 19398698 entries, but only 429365 unique index values or the index values are not in order. See this example:

```
   x
0  1
2  2
1  3

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 1
```

Then do

```
df1 = df.sort_index()
df1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3 entries, 0 to 2
```

Comment: df = df.reset_index(drop=True) was required, but yes I didnt have duplicated values the index just didnt update after each concatination